# Yii 2 URLs that contain text only, without ID

Tags: .htaccess, yii2

So like in wordpress, you can have URLs that are essentially

https://yourdomain.com/article-title/

Without any article id.

How do you do this with the Yii 2 platform? It seems like URL structures require an ID. Is there anyway to bypass this?

Comment: Check this guide  https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-program-with-yii2-sluggable-behavior--cms-23222

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is :

```
http://example.com/<id>/<title>
```

because :

- This will make more efficient from the speed perspective. When using ID in query.
- When your db will be bigger and bigger in the future, Uses of the primary key ID is better for fetching data rather than a string field.
- Search engines indexing the URL complete. So, users when searching in the search engines, it will fetch data LIKELY method, no EQUAL. (for example : google index > http://example.com/123/apple => [indexes: [123, apple, example.com, keywords, description, ...]], when you search 'apple', google will search in indexes that equal by 'apple', that your page have it and show on google results. So don't wory to indexing the your URL.)

In end :

if you are strong to do it, must be use slug field in your table and searchin by it.

- add 'slug' field in your table
- change add and edit actions in your admin module for automatically/manual to set slug field. (etc : I have an apple -> i-have-an-apple)
- change URL creator to example.com/

I hope to help you.